# get elements with data attribute that satisfies a condition

Tags: jquery

I have the following html

```
<ul>
    <li data-index="-2"></li>
    <li data-index="-1"></li>
    <li data-index="0"></li>
    <li data-index="1"></li>
    <li data-index="2"></li>
</ul>
```

How to get all list items that have data-index that do not fall in the range [0,1]

Comment: Okay, and what you've tried till now

Comment: start with [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: And, FYI, `<li>` are not self-closing elements

Comment: Do not fall in the range [0,1] means you don't want those item which has data-index 0 and 1 right?

Comment: Ty, Satpal! I didn't know filter function as I'm novice in jquery. For the rest of you does it really matter what I've tried. Seems like it does. So, first of all I tried to find in the documentation if there is a callback function of the data method. No it doesn't. Than I found a plugin that extends jquery data functionality with the desired callback, but I didn't want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

**Check this example:**

```js
$(function() {
  var collection = [];
  collection = $("ul>li").filter(function(i, el) {
    var index = $(el).data("index");
    return index != 0 && index != 1;
  });
  console.log(collection);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-index="-2">1</li>
  <li data-index="-1">2</li>
  <li data-index="0">3</li>
  <li data-index="1">4</li>
  <li data-index="2">5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
   <ul id="list-element">
        <li data-index="-2">test</li>
        <li data-index="-1">test1</li>
        <li data-index="0">test2</li>
        <li data-index="1">test3</li>
        <li data-index="2">test4</li>
    </ul>
```

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            var listelements = $('#list-element').children('li');
            var result = [];
            $.each(listelements,function(key,value){
                    var temp = value.getAttribute('data-index');
                    if(temp>1 || temp<0){
                        result.push(value);
                    }
                   console.log(result);
            })

    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below JS -

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var arr = new Array();
$('ul>li').each(function(){
  var dataIndex= parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'));
  if(dataIndex>1 || dataIndex<0)  { 
    arr.push($(this));
    }
});
alert(arr.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li data-index="-2"></li>
    <li data-index="-1"></li>
    <li data-index="0"></li>
    <li data-index="1"></li>
    <li data-index="2"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

your html

```
<ul>
    <li data-index="-2">minus two</li>
    <li data-index="-1">minus one</li>
    <li data-index="0">zero</li>
    <li data-index="1">one</li>
    <li data-index="2">two</li>
</ul>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').filter(function() {
       return $(this).data('index') > 1 || $(this).data('index') < 0;
    }).addClass("new");

});
```

Here i have selected and have added a new class to li tags which satisfy your condition.

Refer [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hdpwk03f/) fiddle